# How to run the same specs several times for each startup config

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Jasmine is my favorite testing javascript framework. So far I've wrote specs without any problems.

But one day I've decided to extend my application (it's just simple mind-map tool) with several graph types instead of a single one. Now it's supporting "Wbs" and "Orgchart" data models. Obviously I don't want to duplicate all my current specs for previous data model to the newly created one.

May be in my case it will be enough to fix just one global beforeEach function? Now it looks like

```
var graph;
beforeEach(function () {
  graph = new Graph({
    template: Templates.Orgchart
  });
});
```

So the question is how could I make the same spec to run for each type of my data models. Or if there is any way to pass arguments to `jasmine.getEnv().execute()`? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run your tests in a loop:

```
['Wbs', 'Orgchart'].forEach(function(dataModel){

  var graph;
  beforeEach(function () {
    graph = new Graph({
      template: Templates[dataModel]
    });
  });

  describe('with ' + dataModel, function(){
//your tests
  })


})
```